# Transparent gobo not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I am trying to use a gobo in cycles but having no luck at all. Seems that the transparency is not working. What am I doing wrong? Is the PNG broken?

Thanks,
Douglas E Knapp

Comment: Thanks. Chebhou. Can you do it as part of a spotlight? PS the UV unwrap was not part of my first question but a second try by me to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

- You have unwrapped your object but didn't use the UV coordinates
- you are using the color from the image instead of the alpha
- the non transparent part of the object is better to have a material

here is node setup for the object :

[image]

- if you want the other part to be transparent switch the order of the 'transparent' and 'diffuse'

Answer (score 2):

I'm personally doing it this way:

Create a Sun

Set the Lamp **size** value to 0

Create a plane **in front** of the sun

Unwraping it and extend border edges to cover your scene

Add the gobo (see the network in the GIF below)

**RENDER !!**

[image]
[image: Node Setup]

[Click here](http://gfycat.com/InstructiveGlamorousBlackwidowspider#?speed=2) to see it on Gfycat

Comment: can you please make a static (and bigger and more readable) image of the node setup? and add it to your answer?

Comment: @cegaton Sure. Edited

Comment: nice (second) answer. Good job, keep it up.